# ScheduledExecutorService reuse

Tags: java, executorservice

So, let's say I have the following `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
public class Foo
{
        private ScheduledExecutorService exec;

        public Foo()
        {
            exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(NUM_OF_TASKS);
        }

        public void executeOnce()
        {
            exec.schedule(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Foo.this.doSomething();
                }}, DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
}
```

Now, `exec` is used to execute *periodic* tasks (e.g. directory polling, and etc). But, there's this one task (i.e. `executeOnce`) that is executed *once, but requires a delay*. So, I chose to use `exec` to execute this task, but is this good design? Instead, should I have created a `newSingleThreadExecutor`, and then subsequently called `shutdown`? For instance,

```
public void executeOnce()
{
    // Execute task and wait 'til completion      
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    try {
        exec.submit(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {   
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                Foo.this.doSomething()
            }   
        }).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    }

    // Shutdown executor service    
    exec.shutdownNow();        
 }
```

Are there any **benefits** implementing the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the regular tasks and the one-time task are related in some way *and* the scheduling of the regular tasks is not as critical that a (possible) delay in their execution is a problem, then I'd simply execute the one-time task on the same executor.

The advantage of using a separate executor would be that the regular tasks are scheduled without interference. However `shutdownNow()` would *almost certainly* not have the desired effect here, a simple `shutdown()` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If exec is reused for other tasks, the initial piece strikes me as more elegant.  Creation of a thread is a non-trivial task, even the runnable is only being executed once, the general approach to threading is to creaate a single thread pool and throw runnables at them.  Makes life easier, centralizes thread pools, etc...